# XCODE 6 : How can we run the iOS5,6,7 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I found one major difficulty on Run different simulator on Xcode 6 Bita (3 Version). Please any body help me out on this. I want to run my application on ios5, ios5.1, 6.0, 6.1 and 7.0 , 7.1. (Both iPhone & iPad).

Comment: Just as with Xcode 5.1.1 you will only be able to go back one SDK version. So Xcode 6 will support iOS 8 and 7 officialy. I would also suggest that if you're building an app for iOS 8 the you lowest target should be 7.

Comment: This has been asked many times.  If a version of the simulator is not provided by Xcode itself you are forced to install it yourself from archives of the simulators that you have to maintain yourself.  However many versions of the simulator won't run under all versions of OSX.

Comment: @Trojanfoe : How can we forced install the previous smiulator, can you please explain.

Comment: Because Apple like to push forward faster than developers want to.  They therefore deprecate stuff quickly forcing developers to resort to these kinds of practises.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the older sdk to the directory

```
Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
```

Comment: what is this trying to do?

Comment: first go to same path of your older xcode and there you will find older sdk version , copy from and paste on above address